# Reading object data from json as a link with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I would like to know how can I convert the 3 objects (html, css, java) from a json file structure to a clickable link using jquery and ajax in a dynamic way so every time i click any of these links i can see what it's inside this objects and so on.

json file structure:

```
{
"html": [
    {
        "fName": "John",
        "lName": "Doe",
        "age": 23
    },
    {
        "fName": "Mary",
        "lName": "Smith",
        "age": 32
    }
],
"css": [
    {
        "fName": "Sally",
        "lName": "Green",
        "age": 27
    },
    {
        "fName": "Jim",
        "lName": "Galley",
        "age": 41
    }
],
"java": [
    {
        "fName": "Jonny",
        "lName": "Mile",
        "age": 35
    },
    {
        "fName": "Paul",
        "lName": "Mcmill",
        "age": 31
    }
]  
}
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: no really because i don't know where to start!